# Did physics resulted in invention of maths or vice a versa

Tags: mathematical-physics

Did physics resulted in invention of maths or Maths resulted in invention of physics ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to tell before you define what exactly is considered as "math" and what is counted as "physics".

The origins of math and physics in the modern sense of these words are legendary, and the legends credit Thales with mathematics and
Pythagoras with both physics and mathematics. Their life spans are not exactly known but they intersect.

In this statement the crucial part is "modern sense of these words", that is mathematics with proofs, and physics with experiments and mathematical models. So this is quite a narrow sense which excludes for example all Babylonian and Egyptian and earlier math.

The earliest known experiment which can be considered as true physics in the modern sense of the word is the discovery of relation between the length of a string and the pitch of the sound it produces. This discovery is traditionally credited to Pythagoras. Thales is credited with the first proofs of theorems. But all this information comes from the writers who lived at least two centuries later than Thales and Pythagoras.